# How can I add a dictionary of parameters into a subprocess call in python?

Tags: python

Let's say there is a dictionary called `dict` in which `dict['var1'] = '1'` and `dict['var2'] = '2'` ... I am trying to find a way to add it to a subprocess call to trigger a make file. Currently I have:

```
subprocess.Popen(["make", "make.mk"], **dict)
```

From the command line, this works:

```
$(make make.mk var1=1 var2=2)
```

Is there any way to do this from a subprocess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
d = { 'var1': '1', 'var2': '2' }
subprocess.Popen(["make", "make.mk"] + [k + "=" + v for k, v in d.items()])
```

(My understanding is that you want to execute a command like `make make.mv var1=1 var2=2`.)